# Google Sites: creating a site using a custom template, Scripts not being copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

So I created a template for google sites. This template will be used by a system to create sites automatically. The problem is it seems like the new sites all share the same script( and Scriptdb) where I thought scripts would be copied and each site would have their own version of scripts. The problem is now we will exceed the quotas very fast. What I was trying to achieve was create a site with a certain layout but the data for each site would be different(because they all had different scripts). I thought this would work because I used a similar technique for spreadsheets. I created my spreadsheet, added my script to it and then made a copy and shered it with people who wanted to use it. Then I continued working on the original script without modifying the script for the shared spreadsheet.

Is there a work around for this? Is there anything that can be done so that new scripts are created for each site.

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to the quota page.

**Update:**

So I copied the template to see if there are any differences in the behaviour. By copying the site instead of using the site as a template I get a copied version of the script. The problem is still there. I saw the data displayed was the same for both the original site(template) and the new site. I went on to look at the script for the copied site and it had all the copied version of the scripts. I went to the script box in the UI and looked at the published URL for the app script and i found that the new site is still using the original scripts and not the copied versions. So I tried to manually change the source app script to the copied version and i got an error "**Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.**"

So i went into my drive to check if there is a copied version of the original script and there is no copied version but there is no original version either.

**Update 2:**

Seems like this happens because the newly created scripts are not automatically deployed so google reference the old scripts where by common sense, it should automatically deploy the new scripts and reference the new scripts.